Operation that maps two families of sets to the set of unions of all members of the families?
I am wondering if anyone is familiar with an operation that maps two families of sets to the set of unions of all members of the families? If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are families of set, then such operation may be defined as:
$S_1 \otimes S_2 = \{ s_1 \cup s_2 | s_1 \in S_1 $and $ s_2 \in S_2 \}$
Does it have any applications?
